# Easiest way to store, retrieve, and delete data (a map in this case) in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have been using `SharedPreferences` in my app to save details about text files as it is very easy to access and alter. The problem I've encountered is that when I delete the text file, it's difficult to delete the associated `SharedPreferences` file as it's stored in different places on different devices and there is no generic `getSharedPreferenceDir()` as @CommonsWare mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533286/1902059).

My question is this: Is there another method I should be using to store a `HashMap` that is as easy to use as `SharedPreferences` in terms of creating and retrieving information but is also easy to delete?

I am aware of the `sharedPrefs.clear()` method, but I am referring to deleting the actual XML file and not simply clearing its contents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125296/delete-sharedpreferences-file

Comment: I've seen that and it seems like a good solution (it works on both of my devices), but I've read that some manufacturers store the shared preferences elsewhere. Is this true or is it safe to assume that they'll be there?

Comment: i think it is depend on android os not a manufactures

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll use this for the time-being.